# PowerShell script that Changes a computer name based on the current IP address and lookup from a CSV file

Tags: powershell, computer-name

We have a large effort underway for specific PC’s (approximately 10,000) that need to be renamed.  They are in workgroup mode (not domain joined).  Obviously if we can script this and do it remotely we should.  I have been trying to better understand PowerShell and think it can actually be done pretty easily if I can get the code right.  I need a very simple script that will:

- Get the current IP address of the machine.
- Compare that IP address to a CSV formatted list.
- From the list, use the new Computer Name based on the IP Address and rename the computer.

The CSV would be very simple:

```
IPADDRESS,NEWCOMPNAME
192.168.0.1,NewPC1
192.168.0.2,NEWPC2
192.168.0.3,NEWPC3
```

This is the script I have so far but is not working:

```
$currentIpAddress = Test-Connection $env:COMPUTERNAME -count 1 | select Address, Ipv4Address
$csv = Import-Csv C:\test.csv
$newComputerName = $csv | where {$_.IPADDRESS -eq $currentIpAddress} | % NEWCOMPNAME
Rename-Computer -newname $newComputerName -Force -Restart
```

Comment: I think you need to check if a computer already has the correct name (because it was renamed previously), and you should keep track of all the computer that are OK, so you know you are done renaming... 

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What error do you get? How are you running this on the remote computer and with what credentials?

Comment: @Scepticalist is asking all the right question; in addition, I would ask what version of PowerShell and Windows you are running, and commend to your attention the [Microsoft documentation for `Rename-Computer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments and questions.  I figured it out.  Just to answer the questions and post the correct code for others, here goes.  I am hitting Windows 8.1 x64 and Windows 10 x64.  Powershell 4 and 5.  If the computer name is not in the list, then the script fails (which is good) and does nothing.  Also, we are running this as the local admin account, so the tests have proven successful so far.

The updated scripts are:

The CMD we are using:
If Not Exist C:\Temp MD C:\Temp
Copy /Y "%~dp0RenameComputerBasedOnIPList.csv" C:\temp\RenameComputerBasedOnIPList.csv
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "%~dp0RenameComputerBasedOnIPList.ps1"

The PowerShell script that is running:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$currentIpAddress = Test-Connection $env:COMPUTERNAME -count 1 | select Address, Ipv4Address
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\RenameComputerBasedOnIPList.csv
$newComputerName = $csv | where {$_.IPADDRESS -eq $currentIpAddress.IPV4Address} | % NEWCOMPNAME
Write-Host $currentIpAddress
Write-Host $csv
Write-Host $newComputerName
Rename-Computer -NewName $newComputerName -Force -Restart

The formatted list is like this named RenameComputerBasedOnIPList.csv.
IPADDRESS,NEWCOMPNAME
10.96.21.121,BADCOMPNAME
10.96.21.158,WIN10NAMECHANGE
192.168.0.2,BADCOMPNAME1
10.96.21.52,WIN81NAMECHANGE

Thanks again.